# Speeding up Connection Between Computer and Wireless/Bridged Router

Tags: router, speed, lan, bridge-router

I looked through other questions, but didn't find useful responses.

Our main computer has a dl speed of 6 Mbps, but some of our other computers are getting only 40-200 Kb!

The router is wireless, but all computers are connected using a Netgear Wall-Plugged Bridge XE102, which transmits information via the building's powerline. It can't be the hardware itself, however, because some computers still manage decent speeds.

The computers afflicted are running on Microsoft XP Service Packs 2 and 3, but so are computers that are totally functional.

These speeds severely impede on productivity and are excruciatingly frustrating when trying to cram in time in the early hours.

Could it be an issue with the computer? Location? Router?

Many thanks in advance,

Justian

Comment: are all computers plugged into the same wall-plugged bridge?

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately very little information on this device on Netgear's website. However, looking at a review of the product [here](http://reviews.cnet.com/bridges/xe102-powerline-wall-plugged/4505-3304_7-21057065.html#reviewPage1) it appears that while the product is advertised at 14 Mbps the observed speeds were closer to 4 Mbps or lower.
Now individual mileage will vary, obviously, as many things can influence a power-line network. Other devices plugged into the same circuit (a fridge or microwave will produce more interference than a floor lamp), if two adapters are on the same circuit as each other (the circuit breaker box is where all line noise or ripple will culminate) and the quality and length of the wiring in the house. too, if you have a fuse box instead of circuit box your performance will probably be affected as well.

now i've never used a powerline network before, so unfortunately my answer can only be based on guess work. hopefully someone with more experience with the technology can offer guidance on how to maximize performance .

Comment: Hmm... that's interesting. I'll take a look in to some of your suggestions.